# How to compare array indexes with an integer in C?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement

A grocery store has N different types of chips. Chris wants to buy the chips as many as possible. He has M dollar in his pocket right now and he ask you to help him to count the number of chips he can buy as many as possible.

Format Input:
Input start with T, the number of test cases. For each test cases, there will be 2 integers N and M. In the second line there will be N integers, describing the price of one i-th chips. There will be unlimited supply of each type of chips.

Format Output:
Output starts with “Case #X: ”, where X is the test case number starting at 1, then followed by an integers, the maximum number of chips that Chris can buy

Constraints:

• 1 ≤ T ≤ 100

• 1 ≤ N ≤ 10000

• 1 ≤ M ≤ 10^9

• It is guaranteed the price will be between 1 and 10^6

Sample Input (user input) and Output (output in italic):

6

4 5

1 2 3 4

*Case #1: 5*

3 3

5 5 5

*Case #2: 0*

3 2

1 1 1

*Case #3: 2*

10 5

1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2

*Case #4: 5*

6 2

1 2 3 6 5 4

*Case #5: 2*

1 5

1

*Case #6: 5*

`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= t; i++)
    {
        long long int n, m;
        scanf("%lld %lld", &n, &m);
        int chips[n];
        
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &chips[j]);
        }
        
        if(m > chips[n - 1])
        {
            printf("Case #%d: %lld\n", i, m);
        }
        else if(m < chips[n - 1])
        {
            printf("Case #%d: 0\n", i);
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

`

I made a mistake in the if else part. I compare the m with the whole array, but I think I have to compare the m with the indexes of the array one by one. I don't know how to write the syntax to compare the indexes one by one. Does anyone know how to write the if else statement correctly for this problem?

Comment: To me it seems that you have another more serious problem... your algorithm is all wrong. Either you print `m` or you print `0` or you print nothing. That's not what the task expects you to do... For instance: if `m` is 6 and the cheapest chip costs 3 then you need to print 2 (i.e. 6/3)

Comment: OT: on most modern system `int` should be sufficient so no need for `long long int`

Comment: It's not an answer to your question but I would try like: https://ideone.com/xrsxwz

Comment: So, this problem doesn't require me to use array?

Comment: "Chris wants to buy the chips as many as possible." As many _different types of chips_, or as many _bags of chips_?

Comment: as many bags of chips

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is asking for the maximum number of packets chris can buy, then chris should only think about how many quantity of lowest-priced packet he can buy.

for example, in testcase 1, the lowest price of a packet is 1, so in this case, having m = 5, he can by 5 packets of worth 1.

So, first, you should find the lowest price of a packet (`min` value among the given array of costs)

then print:

```
printf("case #%d: %d\n", m/min);
```